# Ansible find volume disk name

Tags: ansible

I'm attempting to write a playbook to format a certain volume, but I can't get my head around choosing the correct drive

here is what I'm working on

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: create file system on storage lun
    filesystem: fstype=xfs  dev=/dev/mapper/mpath*
```

I'm trying to match any single character after mpath, but * doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildcards wouldn't work in there. You need to get this information in an additional task or alternatively from the setup module.

Example:

```
- command: ls /dev/mapper/mpath*
  register: mapper
- filesystem: fstype=xfs dev="{{ mapper.stdout_lines[0] }}"
```

Haven't tested the above but that is the general idea.

Comment: To whom it conerns, it is a very nasty and unprofessional behavior to downvote a fully working accepted answer with no explanation whatsoever.

Comment: Then here comes your explanation. Neither a working solution nor an accepted one makes it a good answer per se. This solution requires an additional task which, in this case, doubles execution time. Since there is a way how to do it in exactly one task this might be a working solution but not the best. Votes are there to reflect that.

Comment: @udondan You have produced an invalid answer whereas mine is working, probably this is more important. The performance penalty for an additional task is not necessarily double time, but even so, the marginal performance for an additional task in a playbook of possibly hundends of tasks is not always the issue in devops. Not to mention that my suggestion allows granularity for choosing a specific mapper in case of multiple existing. I find your behaviour unsportingly and careless.

Comment: You deserve my true apology. You're completely correct, my answer below is wrong. My intention was not to downvote your answer compared to mine. My intention was to vote for the best answer. Since you can not vote your own answer, I voted yours down. If the other answer was not my own I would have simply upvoted that, since at that time I believed it was the better. Again, my bad. Unfortunately I can not change my vote.

Comment: @udondan Apology accepted, appreciated. I would like to respectfully point out that upvoting the best or downvoting any single other are not two mutually exclusive events. From the help page: "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect". Anyway, again thanks, and for future readers reference, the above comments refer to https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10115